# Solve a system of equations with $\exp$ function

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I would like your help to understand whether the following system admits a unique solution for the unknowns $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_0$.

$$
\begin{cases}
1-t=\frac{\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2(1)\}}{1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2\}}\\
r=\frac{\exp \{ \rho_0+ \rho_2 \}}{1+\exp\{ \rho_0+ \rho_2\}}
\\
w=\frac{1}{1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ 2\rho_2\}}
\end{cases}
$$
$r,t,w$ are known values in $(0,1)$.

Here my incomplete attempt to simplify:

$$
\begin{cases}
\log(1-t)=\rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2-\log(1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2\})\\
\log(r)= \rho_0+ \rho_2 -\log(1+\exp\{ \rho_0+ \rho_2\})
\\
\log(w)=-\log(1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ 2\rho_2\})
\end{cases}
$$
I'm unable to proceed.

Comment: Solve for $\exp\rho_1,\exp\rho_2,\exp\rho_3$ and then take the natural logarithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle r=\frac{\exp \{ \rho_0+ \rho_2 \}}{1+\exp\{ \rho_0+ \rho_2\}}\implies\exp\{ \rho_0+ \rho_2\}=\frac r{1-r}$

$\displaystyle1-t=\frac{\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2\}}{1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ \rho_2\}}=\frac{r\exp{\{\rho_1\}}}{1-r+r\exp \{\rho_1\}}\implies\exp{\{\rho_1\}}=\frac{(1-r)(1-t)}{rt}$

$\displaystyle w=\frac{1}{1+\exp \{ \rho_0+\rho_1+ 2\rho_2\}}=\frac{1}{1+\exp \{ \rho_2\}\cdot\frac r{1-r}\cdot\frac{(1-r)(1-t)}{rt}}\implies \exp{\{\rho_2\}}=\frac{t(1-w)}{w(1-t)}$

$$\therefore\displaystyle\rho_0=\ln\Big[\frac{rw(1-t)}{t(1-r)(1-w)}\Big]$$

$$\displaystyle\rho_1=\ln\Big[\frac{(1-r)(1-t)}{rt}\Big]$$

$$\displaystyle\rho_2=\ln\Big[\frac{t(1-w)}{w(1-t)}\Big]$$

Comment: Thanks: I think $2$ in front of $\rho_2$ has been ignored in your derivations.

Comment: Where exactly did I miss it?

Comment: Sorry: am I right that in the second equality for $w$ we should have $\frac{1}{1+\exp\{2\rho_2\}\frac{r}{1-r} \frac{(1-r)(1-t)}{rt}}$?

Comment: $\exp{\{\rho_1+\rho_1+2\rho_2\}}=\exp{\{\rho_0+\rho_1+\rho_2\}}\cdot\exp{\{\rho_2\}}=\frac{1-t}t\cdot\exp{\{\rho_2\}}$. I got $\exp{\{\rho_0+\rho_1+\rho_2\}}$ by multiplying the expressions for $\exp{\{\rho_0+\rho_2\}}$ and $\exp{\{\rho_1\}}$

Comment: I see now. Thanks